# How to detect a collision in sprite kit?

Tags: collections, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am making a game in Sprite Kit and I have struggles with the collision detection between SpriteNodes,
I've set a sprite node called sprite and a sprite node called platform.
I want the sprite to stop falling when collided with the platform.
This is what I have:

```
        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bal.png"];
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/4 + arc4random() % ((int)self.frame.size.width/2), (self.frame.size.height/2 + arc4random() % ((int)self.frame.size.height/2)));
        sprite.color = [self randomColor];
        sprite.colorBlendFactor = 1.0;
        sprite.xScale = 0.2;
        sprite.yScale = 0.2;
        [self addChild:sprite];
        sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:sprite.size.width/2];
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0f, -4.0f);

        SKSpriteNode *platform = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"YellowPlatform.png"];
        platform.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), -200+CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
        platform.size = CGSizeMake(180, 10);
        [self addChild:platform];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Apple Documentation about *SKNode* and the *physicsBody* property:

> The default value is nil, which indicates that the node does not participate in the physics simulation at all.

If you want your ball to roll on the platform or something you have to set the *physicsBody* property of your platform.

Additionally you have to disable the *dynamic* property on the platform:

> A Boolean value that indicates whether the physics body is moved by the physics simulation.

Otherwise your platform would fall down/move if another physics affected object would fall on it.

Links: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/physicsBody
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thank you for responding, I am understanding what you are trying to say but what is the exact line of code I need?

Comment: As is said you need to set a _physicsBody_ to your platform so you need something like:  

    platform.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:platform.size];

and additionally you must disable the _dynamics_ so that the platform does not fall down:  

    platform.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

Comment: You're welcome :) It would be nice if you could accept the answer (green checkmark left from my answer). That way other people can see that this question has been successfully answered and other people looking for an answer to the same question can find an answer faster.